# Lost ability to choose 3440x1440 resolution after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt, macos

I have an LG 34UM95 connected via TB on a Late 2012 mac mini.

After the Yosemite install, I no longer have the option of choosing 3440x1440 resolution in the Displays preferences.  It worked just fine prior to the upgrade.

I did do the Option->Scaled bit to see the extended list of  choices, but nothing higher than 2560x1080 shows up.

Can I get my 3440x1440 resolution back?

EDIT: my colorsync profile...

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**
I just upgraded from 10.10 to 10.10.2.  Resolution stayed the same! Woot!!  So, either the new update fixed the issue, or it  didn't touch the graphics extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was successful in getting the 3440x1440 resolution back in Yosemite by following the instructions from a [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25831860#25831860) on Apple's discussion page.

The thread is a good read, to put the instructions in context, but the gist is as such...

- Disable the kext signature check `sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1`
- Pull in the `AppleIntelFramebufferCapri.kext` from TimeMachine prior to the Yosemite upgrade
- Make the small edit as described in the thread above (not going to copy/paste his post verbatim here)
- Reboot

Success!!

I had the 3440x1440 resolution in my Display preferences right away.  Didn't even have to hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> to see it.

---

Broken again after 10.10.1 update...

Looking to see if the same fix can still work...

Comment: Let's just hope this isn't broken the instant there's a software update ;)

Comment: crud... c'est la vie

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a late answer, but this issue is now fixed in Yosemite 10.10.2 - full 3440x1400 (on a macbook air you have to close the lid of your laptop, but it works without hacks!)

Comment: I hope you're right.  I'd been avoiding updates.  I'll check it out. I'm running it on a MacMini though, not a macbook. We'll see ;)

Comment: I just upgraded from 10.10 to 10.10.2.  Resolution stayed the same! Woot!!  So, either the new update fixed the issue, or it  didn't touch the graphics extension.

Comment: yeah, I thought the same, my gf has a mb air, fresh upgrade from mountain lion to 10.10.2, never had the hack, ill test in the morning and see if its actually fixed

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a solute - see:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6240037?tstart=0

Comment: That may not work in Yosemite, as Apple seems to no longer allow unsigned or modified kexts

Comment: I saw that.  Checking into it.  I also started a thread similar to this over there.  There may be some progress there too... https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6600759?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: @JoshP thanks for the kext, saved me digging about in time machine :D

Answer (score -1):

Just press the option key while you select "Scaled" and will appear all the compatible resolutions.

Comment: the OP's question already said that doesn't work.