# Native resolution not available on lg ultrawide with mac mini (2012)

Tags: mac-mini, resolution

I'm aware of displaying more resolutions with the option key like in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/149152 but after upgrading to 10.10 the resolution of 3840x(i think)1080 of the lg ultrawide is not available anymore. The display is connected via thunderbolt. It changed after the upgrade, before it was no problem. The max resolution available is 2560x1080.

Comment: I just upgraded from 10.10 to 10.10.2.  Resolution stayed the same! Woot!!  So, either the new update fixed the issue, or it  didn't touch the graphics extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires a kext swap to an older graphics driver. They're probably trying to phase out older mac mini models with the release of the new ones.

[Duplicate: Lost ability to choose 3440x1440 resolution after Yosemite upgrade](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151048/lost-ability-to-choose-3440x1440-resolution-after-yosemite-upgrade)

Comment: The problem is, I do not have a backup of the file `AppleIntelFramebufferCapri.kext`.

Comment: I [wrote a bash script](https://gist.github.com/stnvh/4125d38f20a64da3c702) which downloads and extracts the kext from the 10.9.5 combo update. By default it will copy the kext to your desktop, but if you run it with -c it will do the kext install for you (requires sudo)

Comment: Nice clean script.

Comment: The script does not work any more since there is no Mavericks to download.

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes it does. It uses the combo update package, Not the install DMG.